# Titanium SDK 3.5 not adding Splash Screen for iPhone 5

Tags: titanium, screen, splash-screen

I was using SDK3.4.1 and the build was fine for iPhone, I submitted it successfully on iTunes Connect using Application Loader, but since SDK 3.4.1 doesn't support 64bit it got rejected. I upgraded my sdk to 3.5.0 but this time although I have splash screen present for iPhone 5 (Default-568h@2x.png) but it's keep giving me error that the binary is not iPhone 5 optimized and the splash screen is missing. I'va cleaned, created new project and done everything but cannot solve this problem. Any Help?
Thank you

Comment: Is it an Alloy or Classic project? What `Default*.png` filenames are present in `Resources/iphone` (after Alloy compiles)? What pixel dimensions does the `Default-568h@2x.png` image have?

Comment: Thank you for asking, the splash was one pixel small on the height. IT is fixed. I am sorry for commenting late.

Comment: @Ali Rizwan how did you fix that issue ?